# Ellipsis do not work for static text in ATL project

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

I am currently working on an ATL project with a simple UI.
In this UI I have a couple of static text controls and I want them to have ellipsis at the end when the text is to long. So I set the word ellipsis property in the designer to true (which also triggers end ellipsis and path ellipsis to true).
However during run-time there are no ellipsis, instead the text is only clipped to the size of the static text control.
I also retrieved the style flags of the control (via GetWindowInfo(...)) and the bits for the ellipsis are set right, so I think it is some kind of drawing problem.

**edit:** I found out that the ellipsis work perfectly fine when I enter some long text in the Designer under "caption" and do not change the control. However when I try to set a new text via SetDlgItemText or .SetWindowText no ellipsis appear and the text that exceeds the bounds is just clipped.

As an update, I found out why it does not work. Seems that the ellipsis do not appear when I use tabstops in my text...

Any ideas on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your static is set to single line. IIRC the ellipsis only work for single line statics.

Comment: I have already tried no-wrap and simple (=left-aligned and single-lined) without success